# Empty Field in Modal Prevent AJAX from Running upon accept

Tags: jquery

I have a modal that opens upon click of a button. Then there is a text box that is mandatory if nothing is entered and accept is clicked the pop up saying please enter the dealer name appears. The problem is that on mine it still accepts closes the modal and submits to the database. I think its because of this line when I call JSON afterwards `$('#addDealer').on('submit', function (e) {` and overwrites the alert. Where it should just stop and wait for something to be entered unless cancel is chosen where the modal would then just close. Iv been trying to combine the on submit and .click but am getting no where.

I dont want the ajax to run if accept is chosen and nothing is entered in `$("#NewDealerName")` because there is no need to send nothing to the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/spe2mv5t/

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#NewDealer"><u>N</u>EW</button>

    <!-- New Dealer Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="NewDealer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="addDealer">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="NewDealerLabel">New Dealer</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label for="NewDealerName">Please enter the dealer name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NewDealerName" id="NewDealerName" maxlength="50">
                </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary dealer_accept">Accept</button>
          </div>
                </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End New Dealer Modal -->
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // What happens when a user hits the "Accept" button on the dealer form
    $(".dealer_accept").click(function(){
        var NewDealerName = $("#NewDealerName").val();
        if (!NewDealerName){ 
            alert("Please enter the dealer name.");
        } else {
        $('#NewDealer').modal('hide');
        }
    });

    $('#addDealer').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert($(this).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            // the location of the CFC to run
            url: "proxy/NewDealerSession.cfm",
            // send a GET HTTP operation
            type: "post",
            // tell jQuery we're getting JSON back
            dataType: "json",
            // send the data to the CFC
            data: $('#addDealer').serialize(),
            // this gets the data returned on success
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                window.location.reload();
            }, 
            // this runs if an error
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // show error
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `return false` in your handler if you don't want the form to submit.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spe2mv5t/1/)